# Express - passing 2 empty array not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

This is strange.
I am passing 2 empty arrays in my payload and the post call is failing.If I pass only 1 empty array, then the call is successful.

I am using Express: `^4.13.0`.

Angular Code :

```
$scope.login = function(){        
  var temp = {};
  temp.username = $scope.username;
  temp.password = $scope.password;
  temp.speed=[]; // <---- code works without this line
  temp.notification=[];

  loginService.login(temp).then(function(data){
    $state.transitionTo('root.dashboard');
  }, function(error) {               
    console.log("error" , error);
    $scope.message = error.data.message;
  });
}
```

Node Route :

```
app.post('/connect/local', User.login);
```

I am using passport for login strategy.

In the server, I get this error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (c:\workspace\HotOrNot\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
    at c:\workspace\HotOrNot\main\app\modules\api\User.js:154:13
    at Strategy.strategy.success (c:\workspace\HotOrNot\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:194:18)
    at verified (c:\workspace\HotOrNot\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)
    at c:\workspace\HotOrNot\main\app\config\pass.js:52:24
    at Query.<anonymous> (c:\workspace\HotOrNot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3343:16)
    at c:\workspace\HotOrNot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:244:21
    at c:\workspace\HotOrNot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:407:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:336:13)
```

Any clue will help.

Comment: Hi Karthik,
Can you show your code for the post call on the angular side and the post route on the express side?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "failing"? Be exact.

Comment: Also your code looks  like it is in angular, and not express. In addition, your code works as expected.

Comment: Updated the question guys.Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You can probably refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent
I suspect you're not calling `return` on the error in `User.login` on the server side

Comment: @ralucas if I pass one empty array ,the post call is successful .If I pass more than one ,then the call fails.

Comment: Can you show the code for your `User.login` function?